# Javascript to validate a name field

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using java script patterns to validate a name , but realized I really need to be an expert at patterns to solve this problem.
The function should return true for a name that is made of alphabets, a name can be made of one or more alpha words that are seperated by white space or hyphen
Eg. following are valid names.

1. John Fisher
2. John Andrew Fisher
3. Micheal B Jackson
4. Micheal-B-Jackson

Micheal Micheal-B-Jackson-Fisher

Following are invalid names

1. micheal B jackson  (Assume there is whitespace after jackson)
2. micheal  ( assume there is a whitespace before m)
3. Micheal/ ( this one has non alpha char)
4. -micheal-B-Jackson ( starts with a hyphen )
5. micheal*jackson ( has a * words , words can be seperated only by - or whitespace)

I had written the following function which worked fine as long as the name is not made of more than 2 words seperated by whitespace or - . However the requirements have now changed and the name can have more than one words.

```
function isAlpha(field) {
    var lbl = field.name;
    var val = field.value;
    if (val==null || val.length==0) return true;

    //egs of this pattern 1)Rachit Pant 2)R Pant
    var rep1 = /[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+/;
    //egs of this pattern 1)Rachit-Pant 2)R-Pant
    var rep2 = /[A-Za-z]+[-][A-Za-z]+/;
    //one or more alpha character
    var rep3 = /[A-Za-z]+/;

    var test1 = val.match(rep1);
    var test2 = val.match(rep2);
    var test3 = val.match(rep3);
    if((test1!=null)){      
        if(test1.length == 1 && test1[0].length == val.length)
            return true;        
    }
    if((test2!=null)){      
        if(test2.length == 1 && test2[0].length == val.length)
            return true;        
    }

    if((test3!=null)){      
        if(test3.length == 1 && test3[0].length == val.length)
            return true;    
    }

    alertMe('GL006',field,field);
    return false;

}
```

Comment: If you are doing this for anything but a class project I would highly recommend not restricting names that can be entered. People on this Earth have some strange strange names.

Comment: Cant change the requirements. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp: `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$`. 
And about your javascript code: you don't need to use `match` function, `test` is enough, like this:

```
var regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
return regExp.test(val);
```

Comment: I appreciate your awesome logic more than your willingness to help. Would have otherwise spent half day learning regex and writing this. Also your regex worked perfectly even though my question hadnt clearly specified it should return true for "John Micheal-Jack" ( has both space and hyphen)